# Extjs: how to request model data with json data?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Assuming I have a model:

```
ModelA:
fields: id, name, category
```

I want to get a store, with a json request like:

```
{
   name: 'a',
   category: 'C'
}
```

and the i will give a response will be like:

```
{
    models: [
        { id: 1, name: 'a', category: 'C' },
        { id: 1, name: 'a', category: 'C' }
    ]
}
```

How can I accomplish this with extjs?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want the response to contain more than one record with the same `id` value?

Comment: And also what do you mean when you say _"I want to get a store, with a json request"_

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the docs on the [data package](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/guide/data)  to gain a better understanding of how Ext stores, models and proxies work.  Its not terribly clear what you are trying to do, but I suspect you may need a custom [AJAX request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)